# Do all Deadlands Reloaded Gatling weapons support Auto Fire?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded, shooting

In Savage Worlds Deluxe + Deadlands Reloaded there are RoF2 and RoF3 Gatling weapons. Are both considered Auto and the full "Automatic Fire" rules from the Situational Combat rules apply (including suppressive fire)?

While the RoF3 Deadlands gun clearly qualifies as "RoF 3 or higher", I would assume yes, but the RoF2 Weapons on page 57 of the Deadlands Player Guide only say "Gatling wpns cannot fire single shots and must fire at their full RoF", which does not imply they are auto weapons, do they? Do they only get 2 shooting dice and consume 2 ammo / round, or do the Full-Auto-Ammo rules apply (rof² ammo)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto Fire rules apply to any weapon with a Rate of Fire of 2+, not just those with Rates of Fire of 3. This is confirmed by the first line of the Automatic Fire part of the Situational Combat Rules Section in the core Savage Worlds Deluxe rulebook. The applicable quote is

> Automatic weapons (those with a RoF of 2 or higher) fire much faster - and inherently differently - than regular firearms.

Note that the original hardback version of the Deluxe rules had an error in this sentence, reading RoF of 3. This was corrected in a subsequent errata that can be found [here](https://www.peginc.com/freebies/SWcore/SWDUpdates_Errata.pdf).

**This means that yes, all Gatling guns in Deadlands Reloaded support Auto Fire.**

Comment: I was using the hardcover and was not aware of the errata. So this was the source of my confusion.